# How to add the placeholder in tinymce v4.0

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-4

Hi is there a way to add a placeholder for tinymce v4.0 ?  I need html 5 placeholder implementation in tinymce but it is not there by default.

```
 <textarea id="Text" placeholder="Create your prompt here." ui-tinymce="$ctrl.tinymceOptions" ng-model="$ctrl.tmcModel"></textarea>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237876/how-do-i-add-placeholder-text-to-tinymce maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
 var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
     iframe.style.resize = 'vertical';
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming one is using tinyMCE 4, you could add a placeholder upon init, and then remove it on focus. Remember TinyMCE uses an iframe. 
Needs to be polished for being more efficient, but here is a quick approach:

```
tinymce.init({
  //here all the rest of the options
  //xxxxx
  //Add the placeholder
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function(){
      if (tinymce.get('Text').getContent() == ''){
        tinymce.get('Text').setContent("<p id='#imThePlaceholder'>Your nice text here!</p>");
      }
    },
    //and remove it on focus
    editor.on('focus',function(){
      $('iframe').contents().find('#imThePlaceholder').remove();
    }),
})
```